# Add 6 hours to now() function

Tags: mysql

I dont know if this is possible.
I have researched it and cant find anything.
I want to add 6 hours onto the value now() will return.
At the moment it comes back in a datetime format in the database.

Is there another function where i can add 6 hours onto the current time?
Thankyou

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `NOW() + INTERVAL 6 HOUR`. As an example:

```
SELECT NOW(), NOW() + INTERVAL 6 HOUR
```

Result:

```
'2010-07-16 21:25:17', '2010-07-17 03:25:17'
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use [DATE_ADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add):

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL 6 HOUR);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [DATE_ADD function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add):

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 HOUR)
```

Answer (score 2):

`DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 HOUR)`

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you want DateAdd - see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add).

Answer (score 1):

I'm always forgetting the correct syntax for this, so I find this page of the mysql doc to be a good bookmark:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

It's complete with examples like those that others posted